# static web app auto generated url extraction with CLI

Tags: automation, azure-cli, azure-static-web-app

Is there a command I can use in Azure CLI to pull the auto generated URL Azure provides when a static web app is created? I need it for automation purposes as at the moment the pipeline needs manual intervention to obtain it. I have searched and searched so its either not possible or I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

To get the auto-generated URL of static web app, the following GitHub Az CLI SWA Doc [reference](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/static-web-apps/get-started-cli.md) and commands I used:

```
az staticwebapp show --name krishtestapp-swa  --query "defaultHostname"
```

This command gives the host URL of Azure Static web App.

```
az staticwebapp show --name krishtestapp-swa  --query "repositoryUrl"
```

This command gives the host URL of Azure Static Web App Original Repository.